# I am trying to make default constructor

Tags: java, oop

I have tried to follow all syntax rules but unable to run my code. Error **cannot find symbol**...

> Main class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         Test my = new Test();
         my.disp();
    }
}
```

> Test Class

```
class Test {
    int a ;
    int b;
     Test()
     {
         System.out.println("Default constructor" );
          a=102;
          b=183;

     }
     void display()
     {
         System.out.println("Value of A" + a);
        System.out.println("Value of B" + b);
    }
}
```

Comment: your class Test defines a method display(), but in your main class, you call disp()

Comment: @Syed please always print the error message when ask for help. That is essential, when things get more complicated.

Comment: Usage: What you are trying to write is a *no-arg constructor*. A default constructor is one that the compiler provides if you didn’t write any, so *writing a default constructor* is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: I am trying to run a method by using the default constructor..

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `my.disp()` but there's a `display()` function in the class not `disp()`

Comment: I also corrected this but it is still showing that error " cannot find symbol"...

Comment: Can you provide the full error message?

Comment: 1)java : cannot find symbol  2) symbol: class Test   3) location : class.com.company.Main

Comment: can you give a me a link to understand this constructor concept in detail because i am very much stuck in this...

Comment: Check this [link](https://repl.it/@ShuvoKumar/constructortest) for working code and a tutorial on [java constructors](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_constructors.htm)